# How to retrieve error bar in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I've plot a barplot in seaborn using the follow function:

```
ax = sns.barplot(x='Year', y='Value', data=df)
```

Now I'd like to color each bar according to the following rule:

```
percentages = []
for bar, yerr_ in zip(bars, yerr):
    low  = bar.get_height() - yerr_
    high = bar.get_height() + yerr_
    percentage = (high-threshold)/(high-low)
    if percentage>1: percentage = 1
    if percentage<0: percentage = 0
    percentages.append(percentage)
```

I believe I can access the bars through ax.patches, which returns a set of rectangles:

```
for p in ax.patches:
    height = p.get_height()
    print(p)
>> Rectangle(-0.4,0;0.8x33312.1)
>> Rectangle(0.6,0;0.8x41861.9)
>> Rectangle(1.6,0;0.8x39493.3)
>> Rectangle(2.6,0;0.8x47743.6)
```

However, I don't know how to retrieve the yerr data calculated by seaborn/matplotlib.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like `ax.patches`, you can use `ax.lines`. Of course, I assume that error bars are the only lines you have in your plot otherwise you may have to do something extra to uniquely identify the error bars. The following works:

```
    for p in ax.lines:
        width = p.get_linewidth()
        xy = p.get_xydata()
        print(xy)
        print(width)
        print(p)
```