# How to retrieve seaborn's histplot data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, seaborn

I am plotting a histogram with Seaborn ([cf. seaborn histplot doc](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html#seaborn.histplot)) and the corresponding theoretical gaussian curve using the mean value of my sequence and its standard deviation using Scipy ([cf. scipy normal distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html)).

```py
import seaborn as sbn, scipy, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# loads signal from somewhere else, sequence of floats
# replace by scipy.stats.norm.pdf(list(range(len(100)), 1, 6) for example
# although real values are a bit shifted from that
y = get_signal() 
x = list(range(len(y))

# plot histogram with seaborn
fig = plt.figure()
sbn.histplot(y, kde=True, stat="density", label="measured")

# plot normal distribution based on mean and standard deviation values
ax = fig.axes[0]
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
mean, std = y.mean(), y.std()
x2 = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100)
y2 = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, mean, std)
plt.plot(x2, y2, color="orange", label="theoretical")
```

Now, I want to get the fwhm value of both curves so I am thinking of using Scipy's [peak_widths](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.peak_widths.html) method to retrieve the corresponding information. However, I am unable to do so for the histogram, because I don't have a sequence of values such as `[(bin0_x, bin0_y), (bin1_x, bin1_y), ...]` or `[bin0_y, bin1_y, ...]`.

So I should have two options here : either I compute the histogram distribution with `numpy` or I find a way to retrieve the distribution from seaborn's `histplot`. I am interested in the second option because seaborn can determine a default number of bins that I find alright.

I took a look at this post : [How to retrieve error bar in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47478800/how-to-retrieve-error-bar-in-seaborn)

It says we can retrieve the different lines in the plot through the `Axes` object. But I am not too sure how to go about this with a histogram type of plot. Also, I would like to know if there was a simpler answer that doesn't need to go through all the axis content.

For example, I am drawing the kde of the histplot with seaborn, but maybe there is a way to draw it with another module and use the resulting sequence of values to compute the fwhd value I want ? This should give better results than basing fwhm calculation on the histogram distribution directly. I'd like that but I am unable to get the kde values from seaborn, as much as I am unable to retrieve the histogram values. Maybe scipy's `gaussian_kde()` method would do the trick, what do you think ? Do I need to use it ?

Comment: [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374983/get-data-points-from-seaborn-distplot#comment106906723_37375147) on the duplicate will get you the x, width and height of the bars

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for ! Sorry for the duplicate too.